# sql server converting size to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the result of this query but I'm getting the following error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

```
SELECT d.name,
ROUND(SUM(mf.size) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY d.name
```

Comment: Unless you have a really huge database there is no errors with this code.

Comment: Note that whether you use int or bigint, if you multiply by an integer and divide by an integer, the result will be a truncated integer, and so the Round is doing nothing.  If you introduce a floating-point value into the division, and then call Round, the result will actually be rounded.  You can get different results.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting to bigint:

```
SELECT d.name,
ROUND(SUM(convert(bigint,mf.size)) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY d.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `8` by `8.0` to cast result to numeric datatype. The error is because
`size` column is `int` and `8` is also `int` so result of multiplication is `int`, but as `size` is close to `int type` upper bound 2147483647 you are overflowing the type by multiplication.

```
SELECT d.name,
ROUND(SUM(mf.size) * 8.0 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY d.name
```

You can check it. This will throw exception:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 2147483647
SELECT @i + 1
```

This works:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 2147483647
SELECT @i + 1.0
```

You can read about type precedence https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx:

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence.

Answer (score 0):

It's breaking because when you sum mf.size, it exceeds the max number datatype int can hold which is 2,147,483,647. To fix it, just cast mf.size and alternatively *8/1024 can be written as /128.0 like so:

```
SELECT d.name,
ROUND(SUM(CAST(mf.size AS bigint))/128.0, 0) Size_MBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY d.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            SELECT d.name,
        ROUND(SUM(CAST(mf.size  as bigint)) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
        FROM sys.master_files mf
        INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
        WHERE d.database_id > 4 
        GROUP BY d.name
        ORDER BY d.name
```